# Change/Update the CompletionKey

Tags: windows, winsock, iocp, completion

> ULONG_PTR CKey = 2;  CreateIoCompletionPort(...Ckey...);

Is it possible to change/update the CompletionKey somehow after I called the function? 
Also, an operation happening on both serversock and clientsock (E.g. AcceptEx in a mode that both accepts and receives) returns completion only for the server, can I change that to the Client or even better to both?

Comment: There is no good reason to change an IOCP's completion key. For whatever reason you think you need that, rethink your approach instead. As for `AcceptEx()`, if you instruct it to receive data after accepting a connection, its completion will not be notified until that data has been received. This is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-acceptex): "***If a receive buffer is provided**, the overlapped operation will not complete until a connection is accepted **and data is read**.*".

Comment: The same goes for any I/O operation you perform - its completion is not notified until the ENTIRE operation is finished. As for the Client, I don't understand what you are asking for that. Are you asking how to get a completion notification on the client side when it sends data to the server? You can use an IOCP on the client side with `ConnectEx()` or `WSASend()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change/update the CompletionKey somehow after I
>   called the function?

this is possible begin from *Windows 8.1*

you need use [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with `FileReplaceCompletionInformation`

> *Change or remove the I/O completion port for the specified file handle. The caller supplies a pointer to a
>   [`FILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_completion_information) structure that specifies a port
>   handle and a completion key. If the port handle is non-NULL, this
>   handle specifies a new I/O completion port to associate with the file
>   handle. To remove the I/O completion port associated with the file
>   handle, set the port handle in the structure to NULL. To get a port
>   handle, a user-mode caller can call the CreateIoCompletionPort
>   function.*

note that for initial set I/O completion port for the specified file handle we use [`FileCompletionInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class)

however even if this is possible i think in most case will be wrong and not need do this

Comment: Is it possible to use `NtSetInformationFile` in regular windows application? Is this reserved for drivers?